# Ajax send table row with POST method

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form and in this form I have a table. Now I have Ajax to send with POST method the value on change.

But sometimes my table is filled with 50 results, so it will sent alot of data everytime I change an input field.

Is it possible to send only the values in the row that i'm changing instead of sending all the data of the table?

AJAX:

```
    (function($){
        function urenForm( e ){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'blank.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus ){

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#urenForm').change( urenForm );
    })(jQuery);
```

HTML:

This is 1 row.

```php
 <tr>
      <td><input type='number' id='resourceid_<?php echo $trCode; ?>' name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[resourceid]' class='form-control' value='' readonly></td>     
      <td><input type='number' id='base_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'       name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[base]'       class='form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='lot_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'        name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[lot]'        class='form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='split_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'      name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[split]'      class='form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='sub_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'        name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[sub]'        class='form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='seq_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'        name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[seq]'        class='form-control' value=''></td>    
      <td><input type='number' id='indirect_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'   name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[indirect]'   class='form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='date'   id='datum_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'      name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[datum]'      class='form-control' value='' required></td>
      <td><input type='time'   id='clockin_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'    name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[clockin]'    class='form-control' value='' required></td>
      <td><input type='time'   id='clockout_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'   name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[clockout]'   class='form-control' value='' required></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='break_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'      name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[break]'      class='form-control' value='' step=".01" required></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='worked_<?php echo $trCode; ?>'     name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[worked]'     class='form-control' value='' readonly></td>
      <td><input type='number' id='multiplier_<?php echo $trCode; ?>' name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[multiplier]' class='form-control' value=''></td>

      <td><button class='btn btn-default' type='submit' name='<?php echo $trCode; ?>[update]'>Update</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just don 't send the whole form. Send instead of the form the input elements of the row. You 've got the update button and from this element you can traverse the dom tree one element node up to the parent tr element. From this one you can find all the input elements.

This is just a short code snippet to push you in the right direction.

```
var button = document.querySelector('[id="update-button-<?= $primaryKey ?>"]');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = event.target,
        parent = null;

    for ( ; target && target !== document; target = target.parentNode ) {
        if ( target.matches( 'tr' ) ) parent = target;
    }

    var childnodes = parent.querySelectorAll('input'),
        data = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i++) {
        var child = childnodes[i];
        data.append(child.name, child.value); 
    }

    // place HTTP XML Request here with data var
    // data now contains all input values from the table row you want to submit
});
```

The data variable is a javascript `FormData` instance, wich takes all the input values of the table row. To get the primary key for updating the table row in your database use a hidden input element or a data attribute in your button element and add it to your `FormData` instance.

Comment: The button is only there for submiting the form. When I insert some values I want ajax to autocomplete the form if you understand what I mean. So it has to sent every time when I change an input field

Comment: It 's the same thing. Instead of adding a click event listener to the button, add a change event listener on every input field. The change event listener will do the same as described above. Walk the dom tree up until the closest tr tag and get all child input fields from this table row and send it via xmlhttprequest to another script to update your database table. You can add the identifier (primary key) as data attribute to your tr tag like `<tr data-id="1">`, read it and send it with your input data.

Comment: Another idea: Instead of poluting your form with putting an event listener on every input element, you can add only one event listener on your form element. if the event target is an input element, fetch the data from the table row and send it. This would be much more efficient.

Comment: I'm getting this error `TypeError: Illegal invocation` do you know something about that?

Answer (score -1):

In your php code instead of return all records return last inserted record

```
<?php
   select * from ur_table_name where Id= LAST_INSERT_ID();
 ?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question, or did I formuled so badly?